# Selenium not able to find the search field

Tags: python, selenium, ui-automation, python-behave

Here is the website - https://www.phptravels.net/m-hotels

I am not able to find the field called the city field(see attached screenshot) Even the selenium is not able to record that field. I want to enter the text in that field.

[image]

This is what i have tried but it is not working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/m-hotels")
a = driver.find_element_by_class_name("select2-choice")
a.click()
city = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".select2-input.select2-focused")
city.send_keys("Test")
```

Comment: I get a different selector: `#select2-drop > div > input`

Comment: @depperm - that is not working as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium not able to record the field or able to find the search field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53147289/selenium-not-able-to-record-the-field-or-able-to-find-the-search-field)

Comment: Instead of posting a brand new question with more info, you should have edited your original question and added the details there. You should delete this question and add the details to your first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/m-hotels")

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Search by Hotel or City Name"))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#select2-drop .select2-input"))).send_keys("Test")
```

Answer (score 1):

another alternative, using xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/m-hotels")
a = driver.find_element_by_class_name("select2-choice")
a.click()
city = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//*[@id="select2-drop"]/div/input)')
city[0].send_keys("Jakarta")
```